# Return value from Request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new in Node.js and javasript.
Is it possible return value from request? Thanks

```
 var request = require('request');
//parse text
 function(text) {
 request(text, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    //get title
    var title = $("title").text();

})

I NEED TITLE HERE

};
```

Comment: It is a callback function and its asynchronous in nature. Because at that time of request its not possible to know about when it is going to receive a response. Better assign title to a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

to do that you need to understand the async nature of node, at that moment title might not be available, since the request to get the title is async, so you have to wait for response to come back before you can access it

you can do like this

```
   function getTitle(uri, callback) {
      request(uri, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
           return callback(error);
        }
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        //get title
        return callback(null, $("title").text());
      });
   }

   getTitle(uri, function(err, title) {
     //access title here
   });
```

Comment: How can I call second getTitle? Thanks

Comment: @EK. what you mean how to call second getTitle?

Comment: I want to print out this title on next page. Thanks