# How to return values from Request?

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to return an array from request but its returning null

```js
request("https://***some url*****/", function (err, resp, body) {
        var links_ = [];

        if (!err && resp.statusCode === 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('.div-topics-index > ul > li').map(function (i, links) {
                links_.push($(links).children('a').attr('href').toString());
            });
            return links_;
        }
    });
```

I tried this also [Return value from Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600323/return-value-from-request) but doesn't worked. So how do I return values from the request in NodeJS?

Comment: Did you try printing ```$(links).children('a').attr('href').toString()``` to console?

Comment: Yes it's printing values to the console

Comment: `request()` is asynchronous.  Your return value is only from your callback (which does nothing useful), not from the containing function.   See the question yours was marked a duplicate of.  You will need to use a callback or a promise to communicate back the return value from an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use promise version of request package. It is `request-promise`. The code will look like this and much more simple.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const rp = require("request-promise");

const options = {
    uri: 'http://www.someurl.com',
    transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

rp(options)
    .then(function ($) {
        // Process html like you would with jQuery...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Crawling failed
    });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from callback function. It doesn't make sense. Return statements from callbacks are ignored.